# how fix System.IndexOutOfRangeException: OrderDate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

when run my application then getting this error

> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: OrderDate

there OrderDate is class field.

class file is

```
    public string PageAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
```

and C# code is

```
order.PageAddress = rdr["PAGE_ADDRESS"].ToString(); 
order.Name = rdr["NAME"].ToString(); 
order.OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["OrderDate"]); 
order.CartId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CARTID"]); 
order.Size = rdr["SIZE"].ToString();
```

Comment: c # code                    order.PageAddress = rdr["PAGE_ADDRESS"].ToString();
                    order.Name = rdr["NAME"].ToString();
                    order.OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["OrderDate"]);
                    order.CartId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CARTID"]);
                    order.Size = rdr["SIZE"].ToString();

Comment: please use "edit" link to edit your post instead of putting code in the comment ("edit" is just below tags "C#" "asp.net")

Comment: i cant find out edit buttion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea.

The exception message means that the index `OrderDate` is missing in your collection.

You are fetching all values with upper-case keys. The value `OrderDate` does not match this pattern. Maybe the key is wrong and should be something like `ORDER_DATE`?

However you should check the dictionary or whatever you are using if it contains all the keys. You can do that for example with the [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

Comment: maybe you can say which type `rdr`, your collection is? Then we can provide you some improvements for your code?

Comment: List Type Collection    List<GetTrackOrder> listGetProducts = new List<GetTrackOrder>();

Comment: And please mark the question als closed if your problem is solved :)

Comment: where close button

Comment: you can find a check symbol on the left side of my answer, if you click it this means 'this answer has solved my problem' :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some checking to if the data exists:

```
...
if(rdr has item with key "OrderDate")
{
    order.OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["OrderDate"]); 
}
...
```

The code for checking that depends on what `rdr` is.